# React: Why is array notation used vs. object notation in setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have a component in React which is handling a form.

```
class Register extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      displayName : '',
      email       : '',
      passOne     : '',
      passTwo     : '',
      errorMessage: null,
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    var itemName  = e.target.name;
    var itemValue = e.target.value;

    this.setState({ [itemName]: itemValue }, () => {
      if (this.state.passOne !== this.state.passTwo) {
        this.setState({ errorMessage: 'Passwords do not match' });
      } else {
        this.setState({ errorMessage: null });
      }
    });
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    var registrationInfo = {
      displayName: this.state.displayName,
      email      : this.state.email,
      passowrd   : this.state.passOne,
    };
    e.preventDefault();
    firebase
      .auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        registrationInfo.email,
        registrationInfo.passowrd
      )
      .then(() => {
        this.props.registerUser(registrationInfo.displayName);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        if (error.message !== null) {
          this.setState({ errorMessage: error.message });
        } else {
          this.setState({ errorMessage: null });
        }
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form className="mt-3" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row justify-content-center">
            <div className="col-lg-8">
              <div className="card bg-light">
                <div className="card-body">
                  <h3 className="font-weight-light mb-3">Register</h3>
                  <div className="form-row">
                    {this.state.errorMessage !== null ? (
                      <FormError theMessage={this.state.errorMessage} />
                    ) : null}
                    <section className="col-sm-12 form-group">
                      <label
                        className = "form-control-label sr-only"
                        htmlFor   = "displayName"
                      >
                        Display Name
                      </label>
                      <input
                        className   = "form-control"
                        type        = "text"
                        id          = "displayName"
                        placeholder = "Display Name"
                        name        = "displayName"
                        required
                        value    = {this.state.displayName}
                        onChange = {this.handleChange}
                      />
                    </section>
                  </div>
                  <section className="form-group">
                    <label
                      className = "form-control-label sr-only"
                      htmlFor   = "email"
                    >
                      Email
                    </label>
                    <input
                      className   = "form-control"
                      type        = "email"
                      id          = "email"
                      placeholder = "Email Address"
                      required
                      name     = "email"
                      value    = {this.state.email}
                      onChange = {this.handleChange}
                    />
                  </section>
                  <div className="form-row">
                    <section className="col-sm-6 form-group">
                      <input
                        className   = "form-control"
                        type        = "password"
                        name        = "passOne"
                        placeholder = "Password"
                        value       = {this.state.passOne}
                        onChange    = {this.handleChange}
                      />
                    </section>
                    <section className="col-sm-6 form-group">
                      <input
                        className = "form-control"
                        type      = "password"
                        required
                        name        = "passTwo"
                        placeholder = "Repeat Password"
                        value       = {this.state.passTwo}
                        onChange    = {this.handleChange}
                      />
                    </section>
                  </div>
                  <div className="form-group text-right mb-0">
                    <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                      Register
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

I have a method `handleChange` which will be used to listen to the `onChange` event.

```
handleChange(e) {
    var itemName  = e.target.name;
    var itemValue = e.target.value;

    this.setState({ [itemName]: itemValue }, () => {
      if (this.state.passOne !== this.state.passTwo) {
        this.setState({ errorMessage: 'Passwords do not match' });
      } else {
        this.setState({ errorMessage: null });
      }
    });
  }
```

My question is this: Based on the shape of my state, shouldn't we do:

```
this.setState({itemName : itemValue}, () => {...})
```

instead of

```
this.setState({[itemName] : itemValue}, () => {...})
```

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: That is not “array” notation as you say but how you refer to a property in an object using a variable.  It is similar as saying myStateObj[itemName] = itemValue.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Oh I see, I'll have to look that up! Thank you!

Comment: The relevant search term is "object computed properties".

Comment: Merci, friends!

Comment: Also, do not use “var” but “let” and only use “let” if you intend to change the variable.  I have my teams use only “const” and then we use immutability practices to keep our code less buggy.  Just a suggestion that is out of the scope of your question.

Comment: @westandy No friend, chime away! Greatly appreciated!

Comment: Docs for Computed property names: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names

Comment: I mistakenly repeated what a instructor from an online course about it being `array notation` in my title of my question. But I think I'll leave it as others may arrive to this as I did... But I don't mind revisions to my question!